# what does this mean in suricata rule alert?

Tags: snort, suricata

I installed and configured suricata to give errors. It gave me error like

Jan 13 11:22:18 201612317 01/13/2017-11:22:18.308560  [**] [1:2001219:20] ET SCAN Potential SSH Scan [**] [Classification: Attempted Information Leak] [Priority: 2] {TCP}

I wanted to know what does this [1:2001219:20] mean in this rules ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer. It is

**1 is the classtype**

**2001219  is the alert id**

**20 is the revision**